# How can we implement existing single sign on with azure active directory?

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

When applying single sign on it asks for how to implement it:
1) Federated Single sign-on
2) Password-based single sign-on
3) Existing single sign-on

Can anyone help with existing single sign-on practically how we can implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know how to implement Existing SSO . Just refer following documents.

See more details about how to configure Existing SSO to Applications that are not in Azure AD App galler in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-custom-apps#existing-single-sign-on).

See more details about how Existing SSO work in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-appssoaccess-whatis).

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail, I'll direct you to the entry point for [Azure AD docs on how to implement sign in for all platforms](https://aka.ms/aaddev). I recommend starting with the [auth basics article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios) to get a sense of the types of apps you can build and how authentication differs between them. Then try out a [code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples) to see it in action.

Comment: Hi Daniel thanks for the valuable links. I want to know if an application is already configured with single sign on and we want to integrate our azure AD with it so that AD users can access that application as well.